# Wordpress dashboard posts, pages edit links not working after installing SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I recently installed SSL onto my Wordpress website. After installing SSL, there was a mixed content issue. But could able to fix that by installing SSL insecure content fixer plugin.

But now i'm facing to a edit and delete links not working issue on pages, posts and etc. Apart from that other things are fine in the Wordpress dashboard.

I have added these code snippets already in my wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the wordpress database. The urls are stored in there also, so if the url in there is http:// then update it to https://

wp-config.php (which you have changed already) and the database are the first places to check that.

you want the 'Changing the URL directly in the database' towards the bottom, it tells you which fields to edit.

[Codex - update url in the database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

PhilB

Comment: As i know database values are overriding by wp-config.php values. Is it? And my database options table, i haven't added any protocol in-front of the url. http or https. Just the url is there.

Answer (score 0):

Set wordpress constants as string with your domain name:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://putyoutdomainname.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://putyoutdomainname.com');
```

If you want that login form to dashboard should run via SSL, put also in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

Next logout from dashboard and delete all cookies and log in again (or try private mode in browser)

Wordpress domain name is store in table wp_options in database (I assume default table prefix `wp_`) in `siteurl` and `home` rows.

Adding HTTPS to site that work in the past without SSL is similar to moving site to new domain name. You could move along with [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). Remember if you change URL
 you should update all urls in posts and pages. In WP codex is SQL command to do so.

Comment: These steps are already done. I have added those code snippets in my question. Please check that.